# Tab panel with logo ExtJs

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

I was trying to create a template like in the image in EXT js using sencha architect
[image]

I was tried it using Sencha Architect and created code like bellow,

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MainPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias: 'widget.mainpanel',

requires: [
    'MyApp.view.MainPanelViewModel',
    'Ext.tab.Panel',
    'Ext.Img',
    'Ext.grid.Grid',
    'Ext.grid.column.Number',
    'Ext.grid.column.Date',
    'Ext.grid.column.Boolean'
],

viewModel: {
    type: 'mainpanel'
},
hidden: true,
header: false,
title: 'My Panel',

items: [
    {
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        style: 'background:black',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'image',
                height: 'auto',
                width: 'auto',
                docked: 'left',
                minWidth: 150,
                src: 'http://192.168.1.100/nispera/logo.png'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                title: 'Financials',
                iconCls: 'fa-search',
                border: true,
                height: 250,
                html: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'grid',
                                height: '100%',
                                name: 'MyGrid',
                                width: '100%',
                                store: 'TestModels',
                                title: 'New tab',
                                columns: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                        width: 70,
                                        dataIndex: 'string',
                                        text: 'String'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                                        width: 89,
                                        dataIndex: 'number',
                                        text: 'Number'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'datecolumn',
                                        width: 89,
                                        dataIndex: 'date',
                                        text: 'Date'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'booleancolumn',
                                        width: 70,
                                        dataIndex: 'bool',
                                        text: 'Boolean'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'parkId',
                                        text: 'Park Id'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'name',
                                        text: 'Name'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'type',
                                        text: 'Type'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'capacity',
                                        text: 'Capacity'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'capacityKW',
                                        text: 'Capacity Kw',
                                        format: '00'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'fullname',
                                        text: 'Fullname'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'country',
                                        text: 'Country'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'timezone',
                                        text: 'Timezone'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'owner',
                                        text: 'Owner'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'latitude',
                                        text: 'Latitude'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'longitude',
                                        text: 'Longitude'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'altitude',
                                        text: 'Altitude',
                                        format: '00'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'models',
                                        text: 'Models'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'portfolioLevel1',
                                        text: 'Portfolio Level1'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'portfolioLevel2',
                                        text: 'Portfolio Level2'
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                title: 'Executive',
                iconCls: 'fa-search',
                height: 'auto'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                title: 'Statements',
                iconCls: 'fa-search'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                title: 'Breakdown',
                iconCls: 'fa-search'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                title: 'Forecast',
                iconCls: 'fa-search'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                title: 'Process',
                iconCls: 'fa-search'
            }
        ]
    }
]

 });
```

This created the tab like this but, but don't have the content area full width, and was unable to show. The content area starts only after the image and get a blank space

Answer (score 0):

try using the following property in your grid:

```
flex: 1
```